Wireguard server installed: works, but no connection from client
I have installed wireguard server several times and all times it did work, but client could not connect.
https://linuxiac.com/how-to-set-up-wireguard-vpn-with-docker/
and
https://www.linuxserver.io/blog/routing-docker-host-and-container-traffic-through-wireguard
and
https://www.linuxbabe.com/centos/wireguard-vpn-server-centos
I installed with Docker, without Docker, etc. I installed it on a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04 and a VPS with the same Ubuntu. In the latter case I installed it without Docker using the last of the three URLs mentioned previously.
In this example I list the Raspberry Pi Docker Wireguard.
From my Mac I used the wg client from homebrew using wg quick up ./client.conf which did connect.
Here the server config inside the docker container /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf:
[Interface]
Address = 10.9.0.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <KEY>
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# peer1
PublicKey = <PUK>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 10.9.0.2/32

Here the client cnfig (macOS):
Address = 10.9.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <KEY>
DNS = 1.1.1.1
MTU = 1450

[Peer]
# peer1
PublicKey = <PUK>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 192.168.0.60:51820

Here the result of wg-quick up pi.conf foloowed by sudo wg show:
 sudo wg show
interface: utun4
  public key: <public key>
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: <public key>
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 192.168.0.60:51820
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0
  transfer: 0 B received, 1.01 KiB sent

ip a shows:
utun4: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1450
    inet 10.9.0.1 --> 10.9.0.1/32 utun4

Everything seems OK, it connects to the server, but this shows that it is not actually connected.
Even pinging to the server (10.9.0.1 in this case) failed, let alone 1.1.1.1 or any internet address. And here I am even inside my home networkm being the endpoint the Raspberry Pi.
In all cases I checked whether the server was actually running and it did.
I could not find any errors or error logging: where does Wireguard log its errors ?
Searching the internet reveals many similar issues: users who installed a wireguard server and when connecting to the server, internet connection is lost.
What is going wrong ?
Is Wireguard still in early beta stage ?

have you enabled forwarding on the server like sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 ?

also if you don't want to route through the VPN to get to the internet ( aka split tunneling) instead of forwarding from the server, you probably need to change the client's "allowed IPs" to be the network you want to reach through the VPN.  right now you are telling it to use the VPN for all IPs (0.0.0.0/0). see here for some details. https://danstechjourney.com/wireguard-split-vs-full-tunnel/  you should be able to confirm this by looking at the client route table when connected.

Frank Thomas: yes, net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1.

When I do a portscan nmap -v -Pn -p 51820 it says that port is closed while wg service is running.

try running netstat -ntlup | grep LISTEN | grep 51820 on the server to see if its opened the port. if the listening port exists but its local address is 127.0.0.x, then you need to reconfigure wiregaurd. if it exists and the local address is 0.0.0.0 or an IP that can be reached by the client, then the issue is likely a firewall between the client and the server. Now you previously said you could connect tun4, so it sounds odd that you have questions about the port. if you connect the client, what does its route table look like?

Do you want connections to the Internet (like 1.1.1.1 and superuser.com) to run through the VPN, or do you only want traffic going to the server's network to go through the VPN? can the servers on the server network reach 1.1.1.1?

Even after starting the wireguard service service wg-quick@wg0 start the port was not open. netstat -ntlup | grep LISTEN revealed that only 22, 80 and 443 (it runs Apache as well) were open.
